# Accessing particular cells within dataframes organized into list in R in a "vectorized" way

Tags: r, list, dataframe

This is my first question here, sorry for possible mistakes.

I have got a "tt" list of dataframes after I streamed-in a jason file.
some of dataframes are empty, some have predefined structure, here is an example:

```
> str(tt)
List of 2
 $ :'data.frame':   0 obs. of  0 variables
 $ :'data.frame':   2 obs. of  2 variables:
  ..$ key  : chr [1:2] "issue_id" "letter_id"
  ..$ value: chr [1:2] "43" "223663"
> tt
[[1]]
data frame with 0 columns and 0 rows

[[2]]
        key  value
1  issue_id     43
2 letter_id 223663
```

I would like to get a column (e.g. named "t") with issue_id's out of "tt" structure, so that

t[1] = NA (or NULL)

t[2] = 43

I can do it accessing dataframes as a list elements like this

```
> tt[[1]][1,2]
NULL
> tt[[2]][1,2]
[1] "43"
```

How can I do this in a "vectorized" way? tried different things with no success like

```
> t <- tt[[]][1,2]
Error in tt[[]] : invalid subscript type 'symbol'
> t <- tt[][1,2]
Error in tt[][1, 2] : incorrect number of dimensions
> t <- tt[[]][1][2]
Error in tt[[]] : invalid subscript type 'symbol'
> t <- tt[][1][2]
> t
[[1]]
NULL
```

It should be something very simple I guess

Comment: Thank you guys! I did some adjustments to get atomic vector instead of a list, `sapply(tt, function(x) if(!(is.null(x)|!nrow(x))) x$value[1] else NA)` adding NA instead of default NULL. Thus I get atomic vector which than can be further manipulated easily like factoring or adding to a dataframe as a column. Thanks!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

We can use `lapply` to loop over the `list`.  As there are null elements or if the number of rows are zero, we skip it and extract the 'value' from the other elements.

```
lapply(tt, function(x) if(!(is.null(x)|!nrow(x))) with(x, value[key=="issue_id"]))
```

As @MikeRSpencer mentioned in the comments, if we need to extract the first 'value'

```
 sapply(tt, function(x) if(!(is.null(x)|!nrow(x))) x$value[1])
```

and it would be return a `vector`

Comment: If you are only interested in a single value from each column, use akrun's suggestion with sapply, which will return a vector.

Comment: I think you'll need to filter out the `issue_id` rows to match the desired output. Also, the empty data.frames will probably have to be handled specifically. Unless you have a David Copperfield up your sleeve? :)